# Word 2007 default document will not save

Tags: microsoft-word

My Word 2007 default document will not save and open with the changes.

I can open Word, templates and either Normal.dot, Normal.dotx or Normal.dotm and get the saved changes.  If I close Word and open it or just open a blank document, it appears to pull the blank document from something else, as the changes are not saved.

I have deleted all three and started over, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: try some tests fiddling with /t http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565 you should be able to get it to open with whatever remplate iyou want.  try and figure out what default template file it's opening with.. you could use process monitor filter on winword.exe path starting c:\ or path containing "normal"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem that you're having is that the Word is no longer using the temp folder for caching purpose which is required for drafting just in case your windows crashes. It might be trying to direct to another drive letter for some odd reason. This happen to me before where I open the file but won't allow me to save any changes.
Here's what you can do.

1. click start > Run
2. type in regedit
3. locate this HKEY_CURRENT_USER>SOFTWARE>MICROSOFT>WINDOWS>CURRENTVERSION>EXPLORER>USER SHELL FOLDERS>CACHE  -----> CHANGE: THE VALUE TO YOUR TEMP FOLDER LIKE %USERSPROFILE%\TEMP

this will fixed that issue.

Let me know how it went.